# Code to find matching data and replace the data in the cell to the right

Tags: google-sheets

I have two sets of Data on the same sheet, link below.

One is a very large list of products and their respective quantity in stock. (A:F)

Next to it is a list of (up to) forty of those items. (H:I)

I need a script that will find which of the forty items match the items on the"master list" and if they match change the old quantity (i.e: E3) to the new quantity (i.e: J3).

Hoping someone can help me as it is my last step in the project and I am stumped.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1fCaV9h2YUjgLIH5e5kxkHzvdEQc1IUtB60U356smiAY/edit#gid=1835594398

Thank you in advance.

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Please post what you have so far

Comment: Welcome to StackOverFlow please take this opportunity to take the [tour] and learn how to [ask] and [mcve].  If you want to get an answer I'd recommend you clean a spreadsheet of any private information and provide a public link to it.